# php most elegant function call returning array

Tags: php, function

I am asking your preference between two similar solutions.

First way :

```
public function test($myvar) {

    switch ($myvar) {   
        case 'test1': return [
                          'value' => 'Value of test1',
                          'short' => 'Val 1'
                      ];
        break;
     }
}

$this->test('test1')['short']  // Val 1
```

Second way:

```
public function test($myvar, $key) {

    switch ($myvar) {   
        case 'test1': $array = [
                          'value' => 'Value of test1',
                          'short' => 'Val 1'
                      ];
    }

    return $array[$key];
}

$this->test('test1', 'short')  // Val 1
```

Even if both function return same value, what is the most elegant and readable way for you guys ?

Comment: @DevDonkey No, example code is not welcome on Code Review. Please take a look at [our help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/52915)

Answer (score 2):

For me its the second one with little modifying.
Have a look:

```
public function test($myvar, $key = null) {

    switch ($myvar) {   
        case 'test1': $array = [
                          'value' => 'Value of test1',
                          'short' => 'Val 1'
                      ];
    }

    if(!empty($key))
        return $array[$key];
    else
        return $array;
}
```

Use:

```
$this->test('test1', 'short')  // Val 1
$this->test('test1')['short']  // Val 1
$this->test('test1')['value']  // Value of test1
```

This way you can use your both methods with single function.
Remember, the functions need to be as generic as possible to have less code and do more.
"Code is not an asset, it's a liability. The more you write, the more you have to maintain later." :)